# Apache Tomcat 5.X HTTPS server configuration not receiving POST request data

Tags: servlets, configuration, https, tomcat5.5, google-glass

I am facing a Tomcat Server configuration problem.

I have requested a certificate from GoDaddy and have configured the same with Apache Tomcat 5.x. Following is the snippet from `tomcat5.x\conf\server.xml` for HTTPS configuration.

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
            enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
            acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
            keystoreFile="/path/to/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="xxxxxxxxx"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEnabled="false"/>
```

I am able to access the Servlet deployed on my server using `https://www.exampleserver.com:8443/servletname` successfully

Now I am trying HTTP POST request with JSON data in HTTP Body to the same Servlet and I am trying to log the POST data in the servlet but the POST data is empty or not available.

The following is the code snippet to Log POST data in `doPost` method of `Servlet`

```
    // Respond with OK and status 200 in a timely fashion to prevent redelivery
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Writer writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.append("OK");
    writer.close();

    // Get the notification object from the request body (into a string so we
    // can log it)
    BufferedReader notificationReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String notificationString = "";

    // Count the lines as a very basic way to prevent Denial of Service attacks
    int lines = 0;
    while (notificationReader.ready()) {
        notificationString += notificationReader.readLine();
        lines++;

        // No notification would ever be this long. Something is very wrong.
        if (lines > 1000) {
            throw new IOException("Attempted to parse notification payload that was unexpectedly long.");
        }
    }

    LOG.info("got raw notification " + notificationString);
```

The `Log.info` statement always prints `"got raw notification  "` which means no data was available.

**Previous**

Interesting part is it works when the `Servlet` is deployed or accesses using HTTP not HTTPS

**Update**

I tried curl (JSON data) to the same `Servlet` with HTTP as well as HTTPS but it's NOT working for both. On Local server it's working.

To be honest I don't have much experience in configuring Apache Tomcat Server and SSL certificates. I followed the configuration steps provided by GoDaddy and of course with the help of Google.